# Did I solve this definite integral correctly?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$problem:\int_0^\infty cos(x^2)\ln(x)dx$$
$$Re\int_0^\infty e^{-ix^2}ln(x)dx$$
$$\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^dx, \ \ \ \ x=u^2, dx=2udu$$
$$2\int_0^\infty u^{2s-1}e^{-u^2}du$$
$$\Gamma'(s)=4\int_0^\infty u^{2s-1}e^{-u^2}ln(u)du$$
$$\frac{\Gamma'(1/2)}{4}=\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}ln(u)du$$
$$Re\int_0^\infty e^{-ix^2}ln(x)dx$$
$$Re\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\int e^{-u^2}ln(u)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\int e^{-u^3}ln(\sqrt{i})du$$
$$Re[\frac{\Gamma'(\frac12)}{4\sqrt{i}}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}ln(i)}{4\sqrt{i}}]=Re[\frac{\Gamma'\frac(12)-\sqrt{pi}\ln(i)}{4\sqrt{i}}]$$
$$Re[\frac{\Gamma(\frac12)\psi(\frac12)-\sqrt{\pi}\ln(i)}{4\sqrt{i}}]$$
$$Re[\frac{\sqrt{pi}(-\gamma-2\ln(2))-\frac{\pi^{\frac32}}{2}i}{4\sqrt{i}}]$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{8}(-\gamma-2\ln(2))-\frac{\pi^{\frac32}}{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer looks right to me. Another very similar way is to consider the integral$$\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dx\,\cos x^2\log x=\frac 14\lim\limits_{s\to-1/2}\partial_s\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dx\, x^s\cos x$$The resulting integral can be computed by considering the real part of$$\begin{align*}\mathfrak{I}(s) & =\operatorname{Re}\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dx\, x^se^{-ix}\\ & =\Gamma(1+s)\operatorname{Re} i^{-s-1}\\ & =-\Gamma(1+s)\sin\left(\frac {\pi s}2\right)\end{align*}$$Differentiate and take the limit as $s\to-1/2$ to get$$\begin{align*}\mathfrak{I} & =\frac 14\lim\limits_{s\to-1/2}\partial_s\left[-\Gamma(1+s)\sin\left(\frac {\pi s}2\right)\right]\\ & =\frac 14\left[\Gamma\left(\frac 12\right)\psi\left(\frac 12\right)\sin\left(\frac {\pi}4\right)-\frac {\pi}2\Gamma\left(\frac 12\right)\cos\left(\frac {\pi}4\right)\right]\\ & \color{blue}{=-\frac 18\sqrt{\frac {\pi}2}\Bigr(\pi+4\log 2+2\gamma\Bigr)}\end{align*}$$